# Google charts from MYSQL database

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-visualization

This is set up with a form that input either female or male varchar into a MySQL table with only one Colom that is called Gender I need this to look at that data using google charts to make a pie chat with the number of females compared to the number of males. their are lot of tutorial but they all seem to use a different type of connection them me I have the PDO connection so please help

I'm like 90% sure the error is in my drawchart function

PS: please have mercy on me I am new to coding :) (no hate) 
this code is being hosted at http://webapi.mycscihw.com/

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>web api HW</title>
      <?php
    // db connection

       $db = new PDO    ('mysql:host=50.62.209.160:3306;dbname=jmthom1353_chat;', 'jmthom1353', 'dog123');
    $final = $db->query("SELECT GENDER, count(*) as number FROM MORF GROUP BY GENDER");  





     ?>  
     <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() 
        {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['Gender', 'Number'],  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = $final->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$row["gender"]."', ".$row    ["number"]."],";  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     ]);  



       

        // Set chart options
        var options = {  
                      title: 'Percentage of Male and Female ',  
                      //is3D:true,  
                      pieHole: 0.4  
                     };  

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
       var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }  

      }
    </script>

</head>



 <!DOCTYPE html>  



   <body>
    select gender:
   <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
    </form>



<?php
    if (isset($_POST['gender'])){
$gender = $_POST['gender']  ;
$success= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `MORF` (`GENDER`) VALUES ('$gender')" );
$success->execute();
    echo 'a '.$gender.' was added';
    }
    else 
    {
     echo "<font color='red'>no gender selected</font>";
    }
    ?>

    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>  
           </div>  
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the only other files associated with this is a web.config just so I can see through the 500 errors

Comment: I ended up fixing this there is an extra </div> tag when this is removed it will work perfectly